# connecting google analytics data api to dojo charts - php backend

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo, google-analytics, dojox.charting

I'm looking at feeding dojo charts with data from google analytics, within a Zend Framework app. Has anyone done this or have any overview as to how I would go about it? I see there is a dojox.data.GoogleSearchStore. Does it make sense to have a dojox.data.GoogleAnalyticsStore and is anyone working on something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a project recently doing this exactly - presenting data from the Google Analytics API using Dojo Charts. I'm not sure if the approach I used was the best, but I can at least give you some pointers.

Daniel Hartmann has a [proposal for a Zend_Gdata_Analytics](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Gdata_Analytics+-+Daniel+Hartmann) component. It hasn't been approved yet however you can find his [code on Github](http://github.com/danielmitd/Zend_Gdata_Analytics) and it works perfectly. I used this to get all the data I needed from analytics.

The Google Analytics API itself is quite powerful but it takes a while to get your head round it. Try and understand the difference between *dimensions* and *metrics* from Google's docs. It helps if you think of the service as building queries that return a table of data (like SQL), rather than just one value. In this table, each *metric* you add to the query adds a column of data to the result, and dimensions are used to restrict and group the data overall. So for example:

```
$ga->newDataQuery()
   ->addDimension(Zend_Gdata_Analytics_DataQuery::DIMENSION_DATE)
   ->addMetric(Zend_Gdata_Analytics_DataQuery::METRIC_VISITS)
   ->addMetric(Zend_Gdata_Analytics_DataQuery::METRIC_VISITORS)
   ->addMetric(Zend_Gdata_Analytics_DataQuery::METRIC_PAGEVIEWS);
```

gives you the total visits, visitors and page views for each day.

Analytics sometimes takes a few seconds to respond to queries (especially complex ones) so you'll want to cache the data. In my case I was selecting it at regular intervals by cron and storing it in a database.

On the Dojo side, I don't think dojox.data.GoogleSearchStore will help you. I used a combination of dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore, dojox.charting.DataSeries and Zend_Dojo_Data, but I don't think my requirements would be typical. I'd suggest starting with the basics - get your graphs working with sample (hardcoded) data before your try and drop in your analytics. There are some [tutorials on sitepen.com](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/06/a-beginners-guide-to-dojo-charting-part-1-of-2/) which I found useful.

Good luck!